# Embed tag source Undefined after audio

Tags: javascript

I am using the JavaScript code below to trigger a "keypress" sound each time a key is pressed.
The biggest problem is that if you type too quickly (seems like before the previous clip has finished) the next clip sent to the embed tag to be played has a source of Undefined.

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    var numberOfSongs = 3 
    var sound = new Array(numberOfSongs+1)
    sound[0]= "key1.mp3"
    sound[1]= "key2.mp3" 
    sound[2]= "key3.mp3"
    function randomNumber(){
    var randomLooper = -1
    while (randomLooper < 0 || randomLooper > numberOfSongs || isNaN(randomLooper)){    randomLooper = parseInt(Math.random()*(numberOfSongs+1))
    }
        return randomLooper
    }
    var randomsub = randomNumber()
    var soundFile = sound[randomsub]
    document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = '<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true autostart=true loop=true>';
}
```

I think this is easily fixed by allowing a clip to be played either over the previous one, or allow a clip to interrupt the previous clip, but this is just speculation.

Comment: You should use debounce to handle this.

Comment: Your while loop is really unnecessary, you can just generate a random number between 0 and the array's length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting `undefined` is because one of the values you're trying to get from your array *is* `undefined`.

**Array Issues:**

This code:

```
var numberOfSongs = 3 
var sound = new Array(numberOfSongs+1)
sound[0]= "key1.mp3"
sound[1]= "key2.mp3" 
sound[2]= "key3.mp3"
```

Is building an array that looks like:

> ["key1.mp3", "key2.mp3", "key3.mp3", undefined]

**Random Number Issues:**

Your random number generator isn't helping things at all by generating values outside of your array.

As it is right now, your random number generator will return values between 0 and 3, but your array only has values in 3 positions, 0, 1 and 2.

**Performance Issues:**

Finally, you are re-declaring your sound array and the randomNumber function with each keypress.  This is unnecessary and would inhibit performance, especially when scaled upward.

**Updated Code:**

Taking that into consideration, you something like this could work:

```
var sound = [];
sound.push("key1.mp3");
sound.push("key2.mp3");
sound.push("key3.mp3");

function randomNumber(){
    return parseInt(Math.random()*(sound.length))
}

document.onkeydown = function() {
    var soundFile = sound[randomNumber()]
    document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = '<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true autostart=true loop=true>';
}
```

You can see an example of that in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/egrgnmqp/2/

**Adding More .mp3s**

If you're going to expand this to have more sound files, you can also generate those dynamically instead of having to type out each on that gets pushed into your array.  For example if you wanted 50 sounds, something like this could work:

```
var sound = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    sound.push("key"+i+".mp3");
}
```

This JS Fiddle has an updated example of how that would work:  https://jsfiddle.net/egrgnmqp/3/

Cheers :-) I hope that helps!